# How do I reference sass from a gem in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-7

I've got a new rails 7 application, using sass, and I want to import sass files from a gem (govuk_publishing_components, [per their instructions](https://github.com/alphagov/govuk_publishing_components/blob/main/docs/install-and-use.md)) by including e.g. `@import "govuk_publishing_components/govuk_frontend_support";` in my main application sass file.

When I run `yarn build:css` I'm getting an error "Can't find stylesheet to import" - I assume I'm missing something somewhere which will allow such files to be imported from a gem, but (having looked through instructions on that gem, rails guides, and a google search) I can't find a way to do that.

I don't have much rails experience, so I may be missing something obvious, but the only suggestions I can find seem to involve me getting the gem, compiling the sass (or also getting any gems its sass references), and putting the output into a file in my project, which seems absurd.

How do I set up my project so I can import sass from a gem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using cssbundling-rails to build your assets, when we do that we transfer the responsibility to build your css from rails to node, and is this case is recommend to use node packages to include components and styles, but i found i little hack to make it work with some gems that include assets.

For this gem in specific:

- Adds govuk-frontend using: `yarn add govuk-frontend`
- Then change your `yarn build:css` command to: `sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules/govuk-frontend -I \"$(bundle show 'pagy')/app/assets/stylesheets\"` (Maybe your stylesheet entrypoint is different)

Explanation:
When we add load-path, the sass command includes the gem stylesheet to his load path, and we need another load path to govuk-frontend because this lib uses that govuk-frontend as base.

Obs: I cannot make js works, but you have to do something similiar with your js bundle to make it work.